# First sendkeys automated email doesn't actually get sent from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, sendkeys

this has got me confused...

I have a set of Excel reports I run in the morning that generates six emails each with attachments, plus a seperate report set run on a Wednesday that generates just the one email.

To make these reports fully automated and run without supervision and get past the Outlook security pop-up, I have used the Sendkeys function like this (this is from the 'Wednesday' report):

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = distlist
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "30+ Days and Early Warning lists for " & Format(Now, "dd mmm")
        .Body = "Latest lists attached"
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\" & whoami & "\Desktop\" & outputdirectoryname & "\" & outputfile1 & "")
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\" & whoami & "\Desktop\" & outputdirectoryname & "\" & outputfile2 & "")
        .Display
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Sheets("Run Buttons").Select
```

...works nicely.

Now, my issue is not that this code doesn't work as such, but that the first email never actually gets sent by Outlook but remains displayed and 'stuck' in the Outbox. If I fail to manually intervene and 'Send' this first email, then the subsequent ones also get 'stuck', but, if I do manually 'Send' it, the others flow through as expected.

So, for example, the Wednesday scenario goes like this...

1. Run the Wednesday report - it's email fails to get sent so click 'Send'
2. Run the other, usual morning reports - all emails go through automatically

And for the Mon, Tue, Thu, Fri runs...

1. First email fails to get sent so click 'Send'
2. Rest of emails are sent automatically.

If I reverse the running of the reports, so that the Wednesday report is run last, its email goes through automatically as expected.

My laptop is locked down tighter than a.... so any software 'additions' are not going to happen, likewise directly accessing the SMTP/Exchange server so right now Sendkeys is the only email automation available to me. All the occurences of the Sendkeys code is identical.

As I say, confused!

So do I have an issue with Excel or with Outlook?

...and how do I 'fix' it?

Many thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Is outlook opened when the mail is being created?

Comment: Hi Kathara, Outlook is already open. Although these reports tend to be the first task of the morning so are generally the first to make use of Outlook, there are times when I have to respond to emails first so will have already used Outlook successfully before running (and getting the failures on) these reports

Comment: Ok. Because it once happened to me that I didn't have Outlook opened but "Send" a mail which then got stuck in the Outbox. Can you once try to exchange "Appliation.SendKeys "%s" " to ".Send" and see if this works? :)

Comment: Yes, ".Send" works ok everytime since I have to respond to the Outlook prompt which, in effect, clicks 'Send' for me. It is because of needing to get round the Outlook pop-up that I am using "Application.SendKeys "%s" "

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys might work only if the inspector is active in the foreground. Why not try other workarounds (ClickYes, Redemption)? See  http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52

Answer (score 0):

Add following code before .Display

```
If Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True Then Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
```

Comment: Sadly, dding this line gave a 1004 'Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted' error'.